# CoreData delete object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, iphone-sdk-3.0

Why doesn't the prepareForDeletion: method get called?

I'm deleting an object using its ancestor relationship:

```
[folder removeDocumentObject: doc];
```

The "doc" object gets deleted like expected, but its prepareForDeletion method never gets called... =\

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because it's not being deleted :)

If `[folder documentObject]` returns nil that just means that there is no relationship between the two objects. It doesn't mean that the object is deleted from core data.

Try this :

```
[[doc managedObjectContext] deleteObject:doc];
```

---

EDIT

Using this code I have tested your problem :

I have made a new project with a Document and Folder object in Core Data - it's set to folder <<--> document with cascasde set on the folder relationship.

```
// Create a document and folder and save them
Folder *fol = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Folder" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
Document *doc = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Document" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
[doc setFolder:fol];
[[self managedObjectContext] save:nil];

// Get the document's object id for later
NSManagedObjectID *documentId = [doc objectID];

// Delete the relationship
[fol removeDocumentsObject:doc];
[[self managedObjectContext] save:nil];

// Try to reload the document to see if it's still there
Document *doc2 = (Document *)[[self managedObjectContext] objectWithID:documentId];

// Get a property from the document - this will fault if the document has been deleted. Otherwise it
// will work.
NSLog(@"%@", doc2);
NSLog(@"%@", [doc2 title]);

// Now delete specifically and try again
[[self managedObjectContext] deleteObject:doc];
[[self managedObjectContext] save:nil];

// Should get a fault here
doc2 = (Document *)[[self managedObjectContext] objectWithID:documentId];
NSLog(@"%@", doc2);
NSLog(@"%@", [doc2 title]);
```

The first two NSLog statements work correctly - I get a description of the document and a string for the title.

The second NSLog statements crash because the document doesn't exist in the store any more.

This tells me that just removing a relationship isn't enough to remove the Document from the store - you have to explicitly delete it. However, you say that you think it's deleted. Can you post the query that you are running to see if it's still in the store or not?

Comment: good thought, but in my case the relationship defined is:
folder <----->> document. And it is Cascade so "no relationship" means deleting the object..

Comment: Hmmm, that's odd. Can you prove to yourself that the document has been removed i.e. do a fetch request straight after saving your context just to check that it's not there - either it's not being deleted or it's something to do with your prepareForDeletion method. (or a bug in core data!)

Comment: trying fetch request - and the object is indeed deleted. My prepareForDeletion method is defined in the Document object class as -(void) prepareForDeletion{...}

Comment: And I assume all the other methods in the Document class are being called - CoreData is definitely creating a Document object, not just a NSManagedObject? (PS I'm clutching at straws - I don't know why it's not being called!)

Comment: I may be wrong here, but I believe that the Cascade delete rule is just that - it doesn't come into play unless the Folder is deleted. Delete the Folder and all its related Document objects are deleted in the cascade. But remove the document object from the folder and you are merely removing the relationship. The Document will continue to exist.

Comment: Rizon, is the 'folder' relationship on your Document entity set to optional? If it is, could it be that the document is not being deleted, just orphaned, and that it continues to exist in the store without an owning Folder, and it is not turning up in your fetch request because your fetch request is only looking for Documents relating to a particular Folder?

Comment: @simon - I took it to be if the relationship was removed then any stray objects were removed as well but what you say does explain this bug :)

Comment: as I mentioned, I've tried to make a fetch request and the document wasn't retrieved -meaning it is deleted.

Comment: See my edit - I made a test app to see if just removing a relationship removes the object and it doesn't seem to for me. Can you tell me what you're doing differently?

Comment: Thanks for your effort! Did you define the relationship to be: folder <----->> document, Cascade ?

Comment: Folder has many documents, document has one folder. Cascade so deleting a folder deletes documents. nullify the other way so deleting a document leaves folders intact.

Comment: sorry for the delay! well, you're right man. It turns out deleting the relationship DOESN'T remove the document. even when it's cascade. So I guess now my question is - Can it be defined like this? (deleting relationship=deleting the document object)

Comment: Why not just delete the document instead - that way the relationship would remove it self?